# How can I make javascript function to wait for other function to finish without using any external APIs?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that calls other function containing setinterval. Depending on variables, the second function needs varying amount of time to complete. If first function continues before second ends, hell happends.

The question is, how can I make first function wait for the second function to complete before proceeding with next line. I'm not allowed to use any external APIs. Thanks.

Heres the code but it may be a little hard to understand.
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#canvas { 
background-color: rgba(158, 167, 184, 0.2); }
</style>

</head>
<body onload="room1();">
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border: none;" width="800" height="600"></canvas>    
<script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var gra=canvas.getContext("2d");
gra.font = "20px Courier New";

function pisz(text,x,y, interval) {
x1=x;
var i=0;
var stopPisz=setInterval(function(){ 
if (i<text.length) {
    var audio = new Audio('typwriter.wav');
    audio.volume=.1;
    if (i%3==0 && text[i]!=" ") audio.play();
    gra.fillText(text[i],x1,y);
    x1=x1+12;
    if (x1>700 && text[i]==" "){
        x1=x;
        y=y+22;
        }
    }
    if (i>text.length-2) clearInterval(stopPisz);
    i++;
    },interval); 
}


function room1 () {
text1="Witam cię w mojej grze. Twoim zadaniem jest rozwiązanie zagadek i wydostanie się z labiryntu pokoji.";
text1.split("");
pisz(text1,20,30,50);


text2="gfhfdghd hg fdhfgdfdf fdhfdgdfdf hdgdfhdfgdfghd";
text2.split("");
pisz(text2,20,200,50);

}
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
function f1 () {

function f2(/*some parameters*/ );
//wait for function f2 to end, then proceed to next line of this function

function f2(/*some parameters*/);
//wait, etc.

}

function f2(/*some parameters*/){
//doing something once
setInterval(function(/*some parameters*/){ 
//repeating something for some time, then clearInterval so the function ends
    },some interval); 
}
```

Comment: you can use Promises - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: **it may be a little hard to understand** - so help everyone to help you by providing some simpler code. [How to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Edited, I hope it's now understandable what I want to do.

Comment: There is invalid and confusing syntax in your edited code. You wrote `function f2(/*some parameters*/ );` but I don't think you meant to write the function keyword there.

Comment: I want to call function f2 from inside function f1. The code is right. Look my bigger code above. f1 is room1 and f2 is pisz.

Answer (score 2):

Why you didn't use callBacks?
You can pass any callBack as a function to another function, and call it whenever you want, for example, on http response or after timeOut, or in specific step of interval.

```js
var f1 = function(delay, cb) {
  setInterval(function() {
    // do whatever you want, and now it's time to call your second function
    if (cb) cb();
  }, delay);
}

var f2 = function(param) {
  console.log('second function', param || '---');
}


// Use like this:

f1(1000, f2);

// or :

f1(2000, function() {
  console.log('second function will be call');
  f2('with param');
});
```

Comment: This answer needs more explanation.

Comment: I am not sure it Your answer is what's I'm actually looking for, because it doesn't look like f1 pauses while f2 is being executed and then f1 continues it's work after f2 ends. I might be just dumb and wrong tho.